# Webdriver throwing "Cannot navigate to invalid URL" error

Tags: java, webdriver

Webdriver is able to navigate to the base url but I am unable to perform any actions in it like clicking a link or getting the page title. Even the:

```
driver.getCurrentUrl()
```

is throwing:

`unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32603,"message":"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"`

Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: share your code how you are navigating to the URL in first place.

Comment: driver.navigate().to("http://www.example.com/");

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have prepended http in your URL. I think that will do to solve your issue in case you did not use it.

Change the navigate part as:

```
driver.navigate().to("http://www.example.com");
```

in your second ex too, use the following:

```
driver.navigate().to("http://www.url.com/");    
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login").click();
```

Complete source code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;

public class CheckWebDriver {
  private final WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();  

  void checkLogin(){
    String baseUrl = "http://newtours.demoaut.com/";

    driver.get(baseUrl);
    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("REGISTER")).click();
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
      CheckWebDriver web = new CheckWebDriver();
      web.checkLogin();
  }

}
```

Comment: it navigates to the base url which has prepended http. But when I try to go to a link or click a link its throwing the error. I dont see any issue if I try the same code with google.com

Comment: share your code snippet where you are trying to go to another link..Did driver.getCurrentUrl() work?

Comment: yes. it did fetch the current url. But the next test step is not getting executed. driver.findElement(By.linkText("examplelink")).click();

Comment: Mine is Hybrid framework. When it reads from excel and executes the second test step, it fails. I am observing this for our company website only. I dont see any issues running the same test script for google.com.driver.navigate().to("http://www.url.com/"); driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login").click();

Comment: change this to:     driver.navigate().to("http://www.url.com/"); driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login").click(); – user4884895 1 min ago

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109495/discussion-between-droy-and-user4884895).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109583/discussion-between-user4884895-and-droy).

Comment: Solved this per DROY's suggestion of updating the poi jar files. It helps.